# Is it possible to use node.js in asp.net mvc application?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, node.js, asp.net-mvc-3, terminal-emulator

I want to integrate node.js web-terminal emulator into a ASP.NET MVC application. So before that, I would like to know the possibility of integration of node.js with ASP.NET MVC.

Comment: Check this http://weblogs.asp.net/jongalloway/using-node-js-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application-with-iisnode

Comment: yes, That's work great. This link also helpful for the routing and url rewrite in iisnode. http://www.dotnetexpertguide.com/2012/01/installing-and-running-nodejs-iisnode.html